# Sketch the graph of $ f (x_1, \: x_2) = x_2 $ over $ x_1 ^ 2 + x_2 ^ 2 \leq 2 $ and find the maximum value of $ f $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, qclp

> Sketch the graph of $ f (x_1, \: x_2) = x_2 $ over $ x_1 ^ 2 + x_2 ^ 2 \leq 2 $ and find the maximum value of $ f $.

---

[image]

The graph would be what's inside the cylinder, I think. My affirmation is that the maximum is $x_2 = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You could prove it using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: The two first partial derivatives of the function are never _both_ zero, so there is no critical point in the interior of the disk.  The question is then equivalent to asking for the largest value of $ \ x_2 \ $ on a circle of radius $ \ \sqrt{2} \ $ centered on the origin.

Comment: Note that $f$ is a linear function, so its graph is part of a plane.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, I think it would be for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ is a linear function in two variables, so its graph is a plane. More precisely, the domain $D$ of the function here is the disk $D=\{\; (x_1,x_2)\; |\; x_1 ^ 2 + x_2 ^ 2 \leq 2\; \}$, so the graph is only the part of the plane $x_3=x_2$ above that disk.

> My affirmation is that the maximum is $\sqrt{2}$.

Yes, but it should be proved. Clearly, since $(x_1,x_2)\in D$, we have $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2\le \sqrt{2}$. Otherwise, if $x_2>\sqrt{2}$, then $x_1^2+x_2^2 \ge x_2^2 > 2$. Since, $f(0,\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ and $(0,\sqrt{2})\in D$, $\sqrt{2}$ is indeed the maximum value of $f$ on $D$.